# How to test or serialize struct in Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast payload?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, phoenix-channels, elixir-poison

How to automatically serialize ecto struct to json response in channel test? As I can see in [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html) `The event’s message must be a serializable map`, I found in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188798/707729) and in [tutorial](https://blog.diacode.com/trello-clone-with-phoenix-and-react-pt-3) that when I use `Poison.Encoder` in model then any message passed via Transport (as I understand) layer should be encoded.

Example model:

```
use PhoenixTrello.Web, :model
  # ...

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]}

  # ...
end
```

broadcast from one of channel functions:

```
broadcast_from! socket, "card:created", %{card: card}
```

finally attempt to receive payload from broadcast in test:

```
assert_receive %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{topic: ^t1, event: "card:created", payload: ^payload}
```

then it rises not match error with not serialized struct in payload (I'm trying to match only derived model filelds):

```
Process mailbox:
  %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "card:created", payload: %{card: %PhoenixTrello.Card{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "cards">, ... user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>, user_id: 1833}}, topic: "boards:1833"}
```

How to get serialized json message in test as if it was the client app?

Comment: Why do you expect a client to receive `Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast`?! When we do bullhorn “Hello world,” our mates are to hear single “Hello world” message, rather than to get punched by the bullhorn itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first `assert_receive` the raw message and then `Poison.encode!` and do a second `assert`:

```
payload = "{\"card\": ...}"
assert_receive %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{topic: ^t1, event: "card:created", payload: raw_payload}
assert Poison.encode!(raw_payload) == payload
```

Comment: But why I can't get already encoded payload? I'm wondering where is it encoded by Phoenix and where can I intercept complete response?

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/074a584ae324f78fa89f7ca097c38f8805d3021e/lib/phoenix/transports/websocket.ex#L190-L192) line handles the JSON encoding. This happens very late as far as I can tell, after the Elixir messages have been sent to the test process.